# New Year Chaos (HackerRank problem) - find minimum swap count

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

The goal of the function is to find and print the minimum number of swaps (bribes) in what was initially a sorted array of ints - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem

[image: problem image]

I have passed this problem with the following code:

```
def minimumBribes(q):
    bribeCount = 0
    simulated = list(range(1, len(q) + 1))

    for i in range(0, len(q)):
        if q[i] > i+3:
            print("Too chaotic")
            return
    for i in range(0, len(simulated)):
        if simulated[i] == q[i]:
            continue
        while(simulated[i] != q[i]):
            # do 2 bribes
            if i + 3 == q[i]:
                simulated[i + 2], simulated[i + 1] = simulated[i + 1], simulated[i + 2]
                simulated[i + 1], simulated[i] = simulated[i], simulated[i + 1]
                bribeCount += 2
            # do 1 bribe
            else:
                simulated[i + 1], simulated[i] = simulated[i], simulated[i + 1]
                bribeCount += 1

    print(bribeCount)
```

My approach was to first scan through the array to determine whether it is valid, as 1 person can only bribe (swap) twice, hence the first for loop.
Then I go through each entry in my initial state array(`simulated`) and do swaps until the simulated entry at position `i` matches that in the final array at the same position.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this or whether something can be improved in my approach? I rarely do while loops like this as it seems it could go infinite, but I guess it's okay for this problem as we know only 2 swaps are possible for any entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor stuff:

This `if`:

```
    if simulated[i] == q[i]:
        continue
```

is redundant and can be removed, due to the predicate on your `while`. The `while` would execute zero times and have the same effect as if you `continue`d.

The while itself:

```
    while(simulated[i] != q[i]):
```

should drop the outer parens.

The range here:

```
for i in range(0, len(simulated)):
```

should drop the `0,`  because that's the default.

Since you use both `i` and `simulated[i]`, you should iterate using `enumerate` instead of `range` (though this won't be the case if you delete the `if; continue`). Getting a value from `enumerate` won't be helpful during the value swaps that you do later.

About the value swaps, this block:

```
        if i + 3 == q[i]:
            simulated[i + 2], simulated[i + 1] = simulated[i + 1], simulated[i + 2]
            simulated[i + 1], simulated[i] = simulated[i], simulated[i + 1]
            bribeCount += 2
        # do 1 bribe
        else:
            simulated[i + 1], simulated[i] = simulated[i], simulated[i + 1]
            bribeCount += 1
```

should collapse to

```
        if i + 3 == q[i]:
            simulated[i + 2], simulated[i + 1] = simulated[i + 1], simulated[i + 2]
            bribeCount += 1

        simulated[i + 1], simulated[i] = simulated[i], simulated[i + 1]
        bribeCount += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I see all your points are valid, don't know how I missed some of those :)

Comment: After getting another variable with `enumerate`, how do you keep it in sync with `simulated[i]` throughout the changes? Rather seems inconvenient.

Comment: @HeapOverflow `enumerate` only applies to the current state of the code, where there's a separate `continue` which would use the item from `enumerate`. If that's deleted, there's no advantage to `enumerate`.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't apply to the current state, either. Sure, it would make the condition in the `if` shorter, but then during the while you either have the inconvenience of keeping in sync or if you don't keep in sync, you have the confusion of that. Unless you `del` the variable between the `if` and the `while`, at which point I'd say it's worse than the current state that never created the extra variable in the first place.